# Preg_Match false results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

OK, so I am working on a login system, and I am working on preventing user input that I don't want, part of my verification is determining that the username is only alphanumeric, as well as the password, as well as a separate verification for the email. So I found several examples to use on php.net because out of everything in php, these preg match things make literally no sense to me what so ever.

The problem I am having is false positives. The first two return false when true, and the email verification works as intended, but for the life of me I don't know why. I could simply remove the ! in front to force my intended answer for the expression, but I actually want to know why two statements structured almost exactly the same return different booleans.

```
<?php
$user = "testing2";
$pass = "testing1";
$email = "testing@gmail.com";
    if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $user)) {
        echo "Username must only contain English letters and numbers<br />";
    }
    if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $pass)) {
        echo "passw must only contain English letters and numbers<br />";
    }
    if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])*(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])([a-z0-9])+)*$/i', $email)) { 
        echo "Please use a valid email"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: *“passw must only contain English letters and numbers”* — why?

Comment: Because I would like to get the code functional before worrying with precise filtering.

Comment: Here's a functional password check: `if ( strlen($pass) < 8 ) { echo "passw is too short. Use at least 8 chars; more is better."; }`

Comment: @PeterBoughton: `if(strlen($pass) < 8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a negated character class for username and password, you should remove the negation of the condition:

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $user)) { ... }
```

The above means "if `$user` contains any characters that are not alphanumeric", so seems to be what you want to warn about. In other words, your first 2 regexes are actually *looking* for invalid values.

The confusion may arise from the fact that `^` is being used to negate the character classes in the first 2 regexes, but is being used as an anchor (start of string) in the email regex.

An alternative is to make the first 2 regexes consistent with the last, and have them only look for valid values:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $user)) { ... }
```

The above makes sure that every character of `$user` is alphanumeric.

Comment: Would anyone have a good place for a breakdown of regex? I have searched for one and everything seems to be written for people who have been doing it for years, and its quite bothersome to me that I cannot seem to understand them.

Comment: You should take off the `+`, it’s unnecessary.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.regexplained.co.uk/ or http://regex101.com/ for a breakdown of individual regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two different things:

look for the correct format; *if NOT the string is just alphanumeric chars*

```
if (!preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $user))
```

look for the incorrect format; *if the string contains a not alphanumeric char*

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $user))
```

You mixed them both!